# Dynamics CRM Web API Query - Filter data to based on overlapping dates

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have a an entity let's say - **Event** which has a start date and end date.
I have some start dates and end dates from another database say -**DB**. I need to query data from CRM where the DB start date and end date overlaps with Event.

Psudeo Code

```
GetALL Events where 

DB.StartDate is in Between Events.StartDate to Events.EndDate

OR

DB.EndDate is in Between Events.StartDate to Events.EndDate
```

Can I get a web api query for the above logic?
Thanks!

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have the WebAPI query working to get all __Events__? You've got to give us more than a business analyst's pseudo-code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using the following query

```
$filter=(starttime le DB.starttime and endtime ge DB.endtime) or (starttime le DB.endtime and endtime ge DB.endtime)
```